# How to load the math tesseract module?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, pytesser

So I am new to use tesseract and I want to load the math input module. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use it with the math module as found in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.equ.tar.gz&can=2&q=). How do I made this properly load? Will it load the trained data by default? I've already added the trained data to the appropriate tessdata folder? i cannot figure out what the isocode for the lang parameter should be? is something like mat? There is very limited documentation on this issue and any help would be appreciated.

I am also coding this with pytesseract, but I am open to other modules if it does not support changing the trained dataset.

Comment: Could you post some code to help demonstrate what you've been trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently the iso-639 for "math" is equ even though this is technically not an isocode according to the official list on Wikipedia.